# Flutter: How can I make a drawer opened at the start?

Tags: flutter

I want to make the drawer opened when a user navigate to the screen. How can I do it?

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: Header(),
      drawer: Theme(
        child: Drawer(
          elevation: 0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a GlobalKey and use it as the Scaffold's key.

Then you need to use the key to call `openDrawer` on state initialization.

This is the corresponding code :

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    openDrawer();
  }

  openDrawer() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      drawer: Drawer(

      ),
      body: Center()
    );
  }
```